# What happened?/What has happened?

Tags: tense

In this context which is more correct:

A: We've found him. He's dead.

B: What happened?/What has happened?

A: We think he fell down the stairs/We think he's fallen down the stairs.

Answer (score 1):

Both pairs of sentences are correct, with almost equal 'naturalness'.

'What has happened' is probably the least likely to actually be said, but there's nothing at all wrong with any of the four sentences here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could I mix/combine the sentences as I'd like?

Comment: Grammatically, I don't see why not.

Comment: Yes. The difference, as usual with the perfect, is entirely in how the speaker is choosing to characterise the temporal relationships: specifically, whether they are choosing to present the event as complete, or as having some present relevance. This is in most cases a free choice, and the choice of one speaker does not necessarily bind that of the replier.

Comment: @Colin Fine Do you think "what has happened" is natural in this case?

Comment: @Anouk. I might have answered your question, but now that you have decided to start bullying me by replacing it by a new copy every day I am not going to.

Comment: @Colin Fine I'm not bullying, I thought you hadn't read it, I'm really sorry. I didn't mean to offend.